# The router.query becomes undefined on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I was working on this website it's for driving test for Canadians, the problem i am facing is when someone chooses from three differnet types of quizzes (Traffic Signs, Rules of Road, Full Test) from index.js page and it goes to Quiz page which contain logic for all three different quizzes like using different data and div's which i am getting from query named dataType passed while clicking on quiz option. On first reload everything works perfectly fine but when you refresh the page the router.query.dataType becomes undefined and it starts the different quiz and shows different divs coz basically most of the stuff depends on router.query.dataType. how can i set its value first and then the page loads: here is the link to the website which is uplaoded on vercel: https://driving-test-ten.vercel.app/

and here is the Quiz.js

```
import NavTimer from "@/components/NavTimer";
import Results from "@/components/Results";
import { rorData } from "@/storage/rorData";
import { signData } from "@/storage/signsData";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { createRef, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { darkMode, lightMode } from "../colorModes";
import { useAtom } from "jotai";
import { userData } from "@/jotaiStorage";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
export default function Quiz() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const dataType = router.query.dataType;
    const MAX_QUESTIONS = dataType === "FullTest" ? 40 : 20;
    const RED_COLOR = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
    const GREEN_COLOR = "rgb(27, 148, 27)";

    const [data, setData] = useState(
        dataType === "signData" ? [...signData] : [...rorData]
    );

    const confirmContainerRef = useRef(null);
    const signContainerRef = useRef(null);
    const currentSignRef = useRef(null);
    const questionCountForTop = useRef(null);
    const currentQuestionRef = useRef(null);
    let timeoutRef = useRef(null);
    let runningTimeoutRef = useRef(null);
    // const optionContainerRef = Array.from({ length: 4 }, () => useRef());
    //    const optionContainerRef = useRef(Array.from({ length: 4 }).map(() => createRef()));
    const optionContainerRef = [useRef(), useRef(), useRef(), useRef()];

    const [confirmDisplay, setConfirmDisplay] = useState(false);
    const [currentOptionSet, setCurrentOptionSet] = useState(0);
    const [currentAnswer, setCurrentAnswer] = useState(0);

    const [questionCount, setQuestionCount] = useState(1);
    const [showResults, setShowResults] = useState(false);
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);
    const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);
    const [trackIndexForBoth, setTrackIndexForBoth] = useState([]);
    const [trackIndexForSignQuiz, setTrackIndexForSignQuiz] = useState([]);
    const [trackIndexForRorQuiz, setTrackIndexForRorQuiz] = useState([]);
    const [isTryingToGoBack, setIsTryingToGoBack] = useState(false);

    const [isSignDiv, setIsSignDiv] = useState(
        dataType === "signData" ? true : false
    );

    const [resultData, setResultData] = useState({
        resultDataType: [],
        time: { minutes: 0, seconds: 0 },
        totalQuestions: MAX_QUESTIONS,
        storedWrongAnswers: [],
    });

    const [resultDataType, setResultDataType] = useState(null);
    const [user, setUser] = useAtom(userData);

    useEffect(() => {

        setTimeout(() => {
            optionContainerRef.forEach((option) => {
                if (option.current) option.current.style.pointerEvents = "all";
            });
        }, 1000);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isSignDiv && currentQuestionRef.current) {
            // Set the ror question when isSignDiv becomes false
            if (currentQuestionRef.current) {
                if (!initialized) {
                    currentQuestionRef.current.classList.add("fadeIn");
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        if (currentQuestionRef.current)
                            currentQuestionRef.current.classList.remove(
                                "fadeIn"
                            );
                    }, 1000);
                } else {
                    currentQuestionRef.current.classList.add("slideRight");
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        if (currentQuestionRef.current)
                            currentQuestionRef.current.classList.remove(
                                "slideRight"
                            );
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
            currentQuestionRef.current.innerHTML =
                rorData[currentOptionSet].question;
        }
        if (currentSignRef.current) {
            currentSignRef.current.src = data[currentOptionSet]?.imageUrl;
        }
    }, [isSignDiv, currentQuestionRef, currentOptionSet]);

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
            clearInterval(runningTimeoutRef.current);
        };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!initialized) {
            getRandomQuestion();
            doInitialAnimation();
        }
        setInitialized(true);
    }, [initialized]);

    useEffect(() => {
        confirmContainerRef.current.style.visibility = confirmDisplay
            ? "visible"
            : "hidden";
    }, [confirmDisplay]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const userCookie = Cookies.get("user");
        if (userCookie) {
            const userData = JSON.parse(userCookie);
            setUser(userData);
        }
        user?.isDarkMode ? darkMode() : lightMode();
    }, [user?.isDarkMode]);

    const handleOptionClick = (index) => {
        if (selectedOption !== null) {
            optionContainerRef[selectedOption].current.style.backgroundColor =
                "";
        }

        if (selectedOption === index) {
            setSelectedOption(null);
            setConfirmDisplay(false);
        } else {
            setConfirmDisplay(true);
            setSelectedOption(index);
            setCurrentAnswer(index + 1);
            optionContainerRef[index].current.style.backgroundColor =
                GREEN_COLOR;
        }
    };

    const renderQuestions = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="question-count-container">
                    <div ref={questionCountForTop} className="question-count">
                        1/{MAX_QUESTIONS}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {isSignDiv ? (
                    <div ref={signContainerRef} className="sign-main-container">
                        <div className="sign-container">
                            {/* Image will go here! */}
                            <img
                                ref={currentSignRef}
                                className="sign-image"
                                src=""
                                loading="eager"
                            ></img>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <div
                        ref={signContainerRef}
                        className="ror-question-main-container"
                    >
                        <div className="ror-question-sign-container">
                            {/* Image will go here! */}
                            <img
                                ref={currentSignRef}
                                className="sign-image"
                                src=""
                                loading="eager"
                            ></img>
                        </div>
                        <div
                            ref={currentQuestionRef}
                            className="ror-question-container"
                        ></div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </>
        );
    };

    const renderOptions = () => {
        return Array.from({ length: 4 }, (_, index) => (
            <div
                key={index}
                ref={optionContainerRef[index]}
                onClick={() => handleOptionClick(index)}
                className="option-main-container"
            >
                <div className="option-count">{index + 1}</div>
                <div className="option">
                    {data[currentOptionSet].options[index]}
                </div>
            </div>
        ));
    };

    const doInitialAnimation = () => {
        const onAnimationEnd = () => {
            // Remove event listeners to avoid potential issues
            signContainerRef.current.removeEventListener(
                "animationend",
                onAnimationEnd
            );
            confirmContainerRef.current.removeEventListener(
                "animationend",
                onAnimationEnd
            );
            optionContainerRef.forEach((option) => {
                option.current.removeEventListener(
                    "animationend",
                    onAnimationEnd
                );
            });

            if (
                signContainerRef.current &&
                confirmContainerRef.current &&
                optionContainerRef.every((option) => option.current)
            ) {
                // Remove animation classes
                signContainerRef.current.classList.remove("fadeIn");
                confirmContainerRef.current.classList.remove("fadeIn");
                optionContainerRef.forEach((option) => {
                    option.current.classList.remove("fadeIn");
                });
            }
        };

        if (
            signContainerRef.current &&
            confirmContainerRef.current &&
            optionContainerRef.every((option) => option.current)
        ) {
            // Apply animation classes
            signContainerRef.current.classList.add("fadeIn");
            confirmContainerRef.current.classList.add("fadeIn");
            optionContainerRef.forEach((option) => {
                option.current.classList.add("fadeIn");
            });

            // Add event listeners to handle animation end
            signContainerRef.current.addEventListener(
                "animationend",
                onAnimationEnd
            );
            confirmContainerRef.current.addEventListener(
                "animationend",
                onAnimationEnd
            );
            optionContainerRef.forEach((option) => {
                option.current.addEventListener("animationend", onAnimationEnd);
            });
        }
    };

    const doTheAnimation = () => {
        confirmContainerRef.current.style.backgroundColor = GREEN_COLOR;
        currentSignRef.current.classList.add("slideLeft");
        optionContainerRef.forEach((option) => {
            option.current.classList.add("slideLeft");
        });
        confirmContainerRef.current.classList.add("slideLeft");

        if (currentQuestionRef.current)
            currentQuestionRef.current.classList.add("slideLeft");

        timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
            confirmContainerRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "";
            currentSignRef.current.classList.remove("slideLeft");
            optionContainerRef.forEach((option) => {
                option.current.classList.remove("slideLeft");
            });
            confirmContainerRef.current.classList.remove("slideLeft");
            if (currentQuestionRef.current)
                currentQuestionRef.current.classList.remove("slideLeft");

            slideRightAnimation();
        }, 1000);
    };

    const slideRightAnimation = () => {
        currentSignRef.current.classList.add("slideRight");
        optionContainerRef.forEach((option) => {
            option.current.classList.add("slideRight");
        });
        confirmContainerRef.current.classList.add("slideRight");

        setConfirmDisplay(false);
        optionContainerRef.forEach((option) => {
            option.current.style.backgroundColor = "";
        });
        setQuestionCount((prev) => {
            var nextNumber = prev + 1;
            questionCountForTop.current.innerHTML = `${nextNumber}/${MAX_QUESTIONS}`;
            return nextNumber;
        });

        timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
            if (currentSignRef.current)
                currentSignRef.current.classList.remove("slideRight");
            optionContainerRef.forEach((option) => {
                if (option.current)
                    option.current.classList.remove("slideRight");
            });
            if (confirmContainerRef.current)
                confirmContainerRef.current.classList.remove("slideRight");
        }, 1000);
    };

    const checkAnswer = () => {
        const correctAnswerIndex = data[currentOptionSet].correctAns;

        // Check if the selected answer is correct
        if (currentAnswer === correctAnswerIndex)
            highlightOption(currentAnswer - 1, GREEN_COLOR);
        else {
            //Wrong answer
            highlightOption(currentAnswer - 1, RED_COLOR);
            // Right One
            highlightOption(correctAnswerIndex - 1, GREEN_COLOR);

            const newWrongAnswer = {
                question: currentOptionSet,
                wrongAnswerIndex: currentAnswer - 1,
            };

            setResultData((prevData) => ({
                ...prevData,
                resultDataType: [...prevData.resultDataType, resultDataType],
                storedWrongAnswers: [
                    ...prevData.storedWrongAnswers,
                    newWrongAnswer,
                ],
            }));
        }
    };

    const highlightOption = (index, color) => {
        optionContainerRef[index].current.style.backgroundColor = color;
    };

    const continueQuiz = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <NavTimer
                    setIsTryingToGoBack={setIsTryingToGoBack}
                    setResultData={setResultData}
                />

                <div className="quiz-outer-main-container">
                    {isTryingToGoBack && renderGoBack()}

                    <div className="quiz-main-container">
                        {renderQuestions()}
                        {renderOptions()}
                        <div className="confirm-main-container">
                            <div
                                ref={confirmContainerRef}
                                onClick={() => handleConfirm()}
                                className="confirm-container"
                            >
                                <i className="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    };

    const handleConfirm = () => {
        checkAnswer();
        if (questionCount !== MAX_QUESTIONS) {
            timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
                getRandomQuestion();
            }, 1000);
            doTheAnimation();
        } else setShowResults(true);
    };

    // This function is doing what it suppose to even thought it looks quite ugly
    // Purpose :: It's main responsibility is to get a unique number based on Quiz type
    //      1. It will check the Quiz type if it's just a Sign Quiz or Rules of Road quiz
    //         the logic is quite simple just get a random number when is not repeated
    //      2. But when we have Full Test we are suppose to get a random quiz type first,
    //         After that we need to check if the index which is tracking how many questions
    //         we have already asked in this case we are suppose to get 20 unique questions for
    //         Sign as well we  as Rules of Road
    const getRandomQuestion = () => {
        let randomOptionSet;

        const getUniqueNumber = (tracker, setTracker, limit) => {
            var randomNumber;
            while (true) {
                randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);
                if (tracker.includes(randomNumber)) continue;
                else {
                    const newData = [...tracker, randomNumber];
                    setTracker(newData);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return randomNumber;
        };

        if (dataType !== "FullTest") {
            setResultDataType(dataType);
            randomOptionSet = getUniqueNumber(
                trackIndexForBoth,
                setTrackIndexForBoth,
                data.length
            );
        } else {
            const randomDataType = getZeroOne();

            if (randomDataType === 0) {
                const newData = [...signData];
                setResultDataType("signData");

                if (trackIndexForSignQuiz.length < 10)
                    randomOptionSet = getUniqueNumber(
                        trackIndexForSignQuiz,
                        setTrackIndexForSignQuiz,
                        newData.length
                    );
                else
                    randomOptionSet = getUniqueNumber(
                        trackIndexForRorQuiz,
                        setTrackIndexForRorQuiz,
                        newData.length
                    );

                setIsSignDiv(true);
                setData(newData);
            } else {
                const newData = [...rorData];
                setResultDataType("rorData");

                if (trackIndexForRorQuiz.length < 10)
                    randomOptionSet = getUniqueNumber(
                        trackIndexForRorQuiz,
                        setTrackIndexForRorQuiz,
                        newData.length
                    );
                else
                    randomOptionSet = getUniqueNumber(
                        trackIndexForSignQuiz,
                        setTrackIndexForSignQuiz,
                        newData.length
                    );
                setIsSignDiv(false);
                setData(newData);
            }
        }
        if (currentSignRef.current) {
            currentSignRef.current.src = data[randomOptionSet]?.imageUrl;
        }
        if (currentQuestionRef.current) {
            currentQuestionRef.current.innerHTML =
                data[randomOptionSet].question;
        }
        setCurrentOptionSet(randomOptionSet);
    };

    const getZeroOne = () => {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    };

    const renderGoBack = () => (
        <div className="quiz-backDrop">
            <div className="confirm-go-back-main-container">
                <div className="go-back-warning">
                    Going back will erase your quiz progress. Are you sure?
                </div>
                <div className="go-back-options-container">
                    <div
                        onClick={() => setIsTryingToGoBack(false)}
                        className="go-back-option-cancel"
                    >
                        <i className="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div
                        onClick={() => {
                            router.push("/");
                        }}
                        className="go-back-option-confirm"
                    >
                        <i className="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <>
            {showResults ? (
                <>
                    <Results
                        resultData={resultData}
                        data={data}
                        dataType={dataType}
                        trackIndexForRorQuiz={trackIndexForRorQuiz}
                        trackIndexForSignQuiz={trackIndexForRorQuiz}
                    />
                </>
            ) : (
                continueQuiz()
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```

I have tried to use the use UseEffect with Dependency of router.query but it makes me change a whole bunch of logic also i needed the value of it for these useStates :
`
const MAX_QUESTIONS = dataType === "FullTest" ? 40 : 20;

```
const [data, setData] = useState(
    dataType === "signData" ? [...signData] : [...rorData]
);
```

`

and if i put these also in the useEeffect where i have Dependency of router.query the page reloads before they are Initialized. please help me working on this project from 3 months

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The router object from `useRouter()` may be empty on the initial render, especially after a page refresh, because the page is rendered on the server before being sent to the client. Consequently, `router.query` might not be immediately available until after the component mounts, which leads to the problem you're facing.

First, modify your state initialization to handle undefined `dataType` :-

```
// Initialize state to null or another fallback value.
const [dataType, setDataType] = useState(null);

// Later in your component, after the useEffect hooks:
useEffect(() => {
    // Check if router is ready and dataType is available
    if (router.isReady && router.query.dataType) {
        setDataType(router.query.dataType);
    }
}, [router.isReady, router.query.dataType]); // Depend on router readiness and query change
```

Then, use this `dataType` state for your logic and rendering :-

```
const MAX_QUESTIONS = dataType === "FullTest" ? 40 : 20;

// Use effect for initializing data based on dataType
useEffect(() => {
    if (dataType) { // Check if dataType is not null
        setData(dataType === "signData" ? [...signData] : [...rorData]);
    }
}, [dataType]); // Depend on dataType
```

To handle undefined `dataType` and prevent flash of incorrect content :-

```
if (!dataType) {
    // Render a loading state or return null to avoid rendering with wrong data
    return <div>Loading...</div>; // Or a loading spinner, etc.
}
```